# IIFE creation pattern - but how to support constructor parameters?

Tags: javascript

Being a longtime classical inheritance OO programmer I'm very comfortable with the use of constructors and creating objects that accept required parameters as constructor arguments. For example, an object that sends alerts related to an order might look like:

```
var orderNotifier = function(orderId, notifier, recipients)
{
    this.notifyApproved = function()
    { 
        // use the notifier object passed as ctor param to send notifications 
        // related to orderId to recipients 
    }
    this.notifySomeOtherEvent = function() { // use the ctor params again }
}

//  then use it like
var on = new orderNotifier(12345, new BasicNotifier(), someArrayOfEmails);
on.notifyApproved();
```

So that is a contrived example but exemplifies (IMHO) the value of a parameterized constructor. Specifically:

1. Passing state to the object in a single statement
2. Simplified method signatures
3. Internal state is hidden

Appreciating that the constructor creation pattern in JavaScript doesn't very well support information hiding, I was attracted to the [Immediately Invoked Function Expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression) (IIFE) pattern with its closures and stronger access control. Now I've run up against the fact that I can't pass object construction parameters using the IIFE pattern, or at least I don't understand how I can.

I know you can pass parameters to the anonymous function like so:

```
(function(param){})(someVar);
```

But that isn't the same as explicitly creating a new object and passing parameters to the constructor. By the very nature of the IIFE pattern I don't necessarily have the data to pass to the object yet.

My IIFE version of the above would like like:

```
var orderNotifier = (function()
{
    var privateHelperMethod = function() { return 'blahblahblah'; };

    return {
        notifyApproved: function(orderId, notifier, recipient)
        { 
            // use the notifier object passed as ctor param to send notifications 
            // related to orderId to recipients
            var msg = privateHelperMethod() 
        },

        notifySomeOtherEvent: function(orderId, notifier, recipient)
        {
            // use the ctor params again
            var msg = privateHelperMethod();
        }
    };
}}();
```

So I must ask experienced, progressive JavaScript pros: Using standard ECMAScript 5 language features, what is the best practice (or maybe even just a common practice) of creating an object with the IIFE pattern and providing object state in a single operation? (Other than exposing a setState() or similar method.) In other words: How can I have my cake and eat it too?

Comment: I think you're going to have to show the IIFE constructor pattern you're talking about.  We all know what an IIFE is, but not what you mean by an IIFE constructor pattern so don't really know what problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: Why don't you have the data to pass to the object when creating it? No standard pattern deals with that. Why would you create the object at all before it is usable?

Comment: Why are you passing the state as a parameter? Looks like `new BasicNotifier()` and these things should be created *inside* the constructor. Also, why do you think that the constructor creation pattern does not support information hiding? You can use local variables and closures to access them just as you do in an IIFE.

Comment: @Bergi because with IIFE the object is created as soon as it's interpreted. Other dependant operations have not completed, or even started.

Comment: @Bergi To support loose coupling, or somewhat loose coupling I prefer to inject dependencies into objects when possible. If I added new BasicNotifier() inside the orderNotifier object and later wanted to change to a diff. implementation I would need to mess around with the orderNotifier code instead of just passing a different concrete implementation into it.

Comment: @SteveK: Then why not just place the IIFE in that place where the data is available? Nothing should force you to create the object immediately.

Comment: @jfriend00 Done - added IIFE example

Comment: @Bergi the Rhino engine makes it execute immediately. When it parses the file, that object gets created and I have no opportunity to pass non-static data.

Comment: @SteveK: Yes, it is *executed* immediately. But *your code* is creating the object, which could be avoided by changing the code. Again: Where does the non-static data come from (and when)?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your IIFE constructor pattern creates a singleton (only one object, ever).  It doesn't expose a constructor so it can't be used to create more objects.  As such, you can pass any info you want into the singleton via the arguments to the IIFE or just code those arguments right into the implementation.

This is why I wanted you to show us what design pattern you were actually talking about because this particular pattern isn't a general purpose constructor and isn't designed to create multiple objects.  It creates a singleton object.  That's what it is best for.  If the returned object exposed functions that could be used as constructors, then they could take arguments just like other constructors.

I don't see a problem here.  I don't see that there is an issue to be solved.

Per your comments, if you want to pass non-static data into the IIFE, then you either have to locate the IIFE after the creation of the non-static data (so that data is available before the IIFE runs), select a different design pattern (e.g. use a traditional constructor) or use an IIFE that creates a constructor (which you can call later), rather than an object.

---

For example, here's an IIFE that creates a constructor:

```
var OrderNotifier = (function()
{
    //  private stuff would go here
    //  shared by all instances


    return function(/* constructor args go here */) {

        // per-instance private vars here

        return {
            notifyApproved: function(orderId, notifier, recipient)
            { 
                // use the notifier object passed as ctor param to send notifications 
                // related to orderId to recipients 
            },

            notifySomeOtherEvent: function(orderId, notifier, recipient)
            {
                // use the ctor params again
            }
        };
    }

}}();

// sometime later in your code
var notifier = new OrderNotifier(/* args here */);
```

Comment: Is it accurate to say that the IIFE pattern will only create a Singleton? I'm not arguing with you, this discussion is what I was hoping for. I'm trying to see how I can have private methods and a constructor. When you create function-scoped methods in a constructor you don't have access to the this pointer in the "private" methods, that is why IIFE was attractive to me. I suppose this is why the 'var that = this' pattern exists, no?

Comment: @SteveK - Your IIFE only creates a singleton, but I just added an IIFE that makes a traditional constructor which can then be called as many times as you want (and they all share access to the same private data).  IIFEs are very flexible and can be used in many ways.  Your particular example was only creating a singleton, but that is just one of many ways to use an IIFE.

Comment: I see what you did - interesting. So the IIFE is creating the scope to support privacy and is returning the constructor function which has access to the parent scope. In order for the IIFE scope (i.e. "private stuff") to utilize the constructor parameters I would need to assign the constructor parameters to IIFE scoped variables. 
OK, I will play with this. Thank you for illustrating this pattern, it's interesting.

Comment: @SteveK - A closure just creates a place to store private stuff and there are a lot of different ways to use it depending upon what you return out of it or callbacks you place in it.

Comment: @jfriend00 This is not any singleton more this is factory pattern, every time function is called IIFE is returning new object, objects has the same properties but it is not object reference as it should be in singleton.

Comment: @MaciejSikora - Yes, this is not a singleton pattern.  The OP asked for an IIFE that provided access to a constructor function that can take parameters, but could use the privacy of an IIFE.  I don't see anywhere the OP asked for a singleton.

Answer (score 1):

The two options you provide essentially have two different uses (and also, the first method is best used with a prototype).

Prototypal object creation

```
function OrderNotifier(orderId, notifier, recipients)
{
 this.orderId = orderId;
 this.notifier = notifier;
 this.recipients = recipients;
}
OrderNotifier.prototype.notifyApproved = function()
{ 
    // use the notifier object passed as ctor param to send notifications
    // in the form of this.notifier
    // related to orderId to recipients 
    // accessed through this.orderId and this.recipients
}
OrderNotifier.prototype.notifySomeOtherEvent = function() { 
    // use the ctor params again 
}
```

and used

```
var on = new OrderNotifier(12345, new BasicNotifier(), someArrayOfEmails);
on.notifyApproved();
```

This approach is basically for creating objects which are going to have their own unique values but share the same configuration and prototype (behaviors). Using an IIFE (Immediately Invoked Function Expression) is really for a different operation. It can be useful for protecting the global namespace from variable pollution. If there is some work that needs to be done, but the variables shouldn't stick around, then that is where IIFE's shine. In addition, they are very useful for closing over values. However, an IIFE generally runs once and is gone, and as a result it does not need instantiation. Some variables can be passed in if they are to be used or closed over in the function, but in general, the entire IIFE is gone once executed (although a common pattern is to have it modify global state for a library - jQuery does this).

---

*Edit*

In your late edit, you create a closure for "private stuff would go here", but it is too abstract of an example to really highlight any benefit. Private stuff could go there, but really, it would be static and could simply have been moved into notifyApproved or notifySomeOtherEvent. It is really a misuse of the IIFE because this could simply be

```
var orderNotifier = {
 notifyApproved: function(orderId,notifier,recipient){
  //store "private" information here
 },
 notifySomeOtherEvent : function(orderId,notifier,recipient){
  //store "private" information here
 }
};
```

It would be possible for you to go back, and edit in the IIFE to accept values on load to be passed in and then stored as "private", but the only benefit of doing that would be to close over the values at the time that the script is first executing.

Comment: Why is the first method better for using prototype? If I would have a large amount of instances sharing methods, yes or wanted to derive new objects from it, fine. But for a simple object to encapsulate functionality and data I think a function object with methods is OK, isn't it? In your example you've take state that was hidden and made it public, I'd say that's a substantial impact. Imagine this.notifier = null or this.recipients = 'joe'

Comment: @SteveK - A simple object to encapsulate functionality sounds to me like all the variables should just be wrapped in the IIFE including the functions. However, your examples are far too abstract to be useful for analysis here. To get better feedback it would be helpful if you could actually create code which reproduces or compares and contrasts an issue you are facing.

Comment: OK, was trying to keep it light and easy but I see your point on a better example. I'm not going to start from scratch at this point, but I have added an example of a private method to the IIFE example. Hopefully this will shed a bit more light on what I'm after.

Comment: @SteveK - The most recent edit that you have now produced contains essentially the "module pattern". The more complex the contents of the IIFE becomes, the more it becomes a large singleton (again, reference jQuery). There is nothing wrong with using the module pattern if it is only being used once, however, if it is only being once then why even encapsulate it like this? Moreover, if you are returning an object, keep in mind that the use of `new` is not required since there is no real object state involved.